# plotting columns with different dimentions from text file using plt.plotfile

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a text file with four columns. The first and the second are dates, and the third and fourth are data. I am able to plot the first and the second columns using the following code. However, the code does not work to plot the third and fourth. I need to plot them in the same graph (graph with 2 curves).

**Data**:

```
2011-01-01,0.860862069,2011-01-01,4.0491525424
2011-01-02,0.593125,2011-01-26,0.775
2011-01-03,0.5793617021,2011-01-27,0.6044210526
2011-01-04,0.5760416667,2011-01-28,0.5938947368
2011-01-05,0.5657446809,2011-01-29,0.5843157895
2011-01-06,0.5635416667,2011-01-30,0.5675789474
2011-01-07,0.5617021277,2011-01-31,0.5555789474
2011-01-08,0.560625,2011-02-01,0.5567368421
2011-01-09,0.5563829787,2011-02-02,0.5470526316
2011-01-10,0.5704166667,2011-02-03,0.5690526316
2011-01-11,0.5574468085,2011-02-04,0.5907368421
2011-01-12,0.5589583333,2011-02-05,0.5394736842
2011-01-13,0.5621276596,2011-02-06,0.5182105263
2011-01-14,0.55125,2011-02-07,0.5251578947
2011-01-15,0.5436170213,2011-02-08,0.5234736842
2011-01-16,0.5295833333,2011-02-09,0.5109473684
2011-01-17,0.5231914894,2011-02-10,0.5206315789
2011-01-18,0.5233333333,2011-02-11,0.5374736842
2011-01-19,0.5532,2011-02-12,0.524
2011-01-20,0.51,2011-02-13,0.4884210526
2011-01-21,0.454,2011-02-14,0.4438947368
2011-02-06,0.5251612903,2011-02-15,0.4503157895
2011-02-07,0.5231914894,2011-02-16,0.4554736842
2011-02-08,0.51875,2011-02-17,0.4391578947
2011-02-09,0.5029787234,2011-02-18,0.42
2011-02-10,0.4839583333
2011-02-11,0.4731914894
2011-02-12,0.47
2011-02-13,0.4804255319
2011-02-14,0.4904166667
2011-02-15,0.4936170213
```

**Code**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fname_read = '/home/omar/Desktop/2011.csv'

plt.plotfile(fname_read, delimiter=',', cols=(0, 1, 3), 
             names=('day','data'), marker='o')

plt.show()
```

**Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
File "/home/omar/python/plot_txt.py", line 13, in <module>
names=('Year','Topsoil Moisture'), marker='o')
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2343, in plotfile
yname, y = getname_val(cols[i])
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2318, in getname_val
name = r.dtype.names[int(identifier)]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: I reformatted your question so your data sample was formatted on screen as it was in the post source. This reveals that the last six lines of your file have two columns, not four.

Answer (score 0):

Omar, are you sure your data is formatted correctly? Look at the second-to-last line of your data file:

> 2011-02-09,0.5029787234,2011-02-18,0.42 2011-02-10,0.4839583333
>   2011-02-11,0.4731914894

You use commas as delimiters, but there are also blanks in there. I am not sure, but if blanks are interpreted as newlines, the last item in that second-to-last line

> 2011-02-11,0.4731914894

only has two elements, which might cause your IndexError.

Comment: the new format is correct. the third and the fourth columns do not have the same dimensions of the first and the second. Blanks are new lines

Comment: @ mommermi: the two elements make that problem and I need to overcome it with keeping the column structure as it is

Comment: @Omar: I am not sure how you want to plot the third and fourth column, if some of your data rows only have two columns. All rows have to have the same number of columns...